# How to consume the output of Cosmos Change streams

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, changestream

I am working with the change stream functionality of Cosmos for mongo, i am able to get the incremental data using this functionality.
Below is one document which was extracted using change stream:

```
{_id=647ef4539a6aa91e4862e12b, id=821, stuid=33, Gender=female, Street=76, DOB=01-01-1990}
```

When i try to use the same document to insert data into Cosmos for mongo DB, it fails.
I need to insert the data back into Cosmos for mongo. Is there any function that i can use to get this data back into a format which can be inserted back into Cosmos for mongo db.

Comment: What is giving you that output? `DOB=01-01-1990` isn't valid BSON or valid JSON and this won't be the raw output from the change streams. This is not the raw format that Cosmos change streams would give you. That just gives you a BSON document

Comment: Thanks @Martin Smith, This is the output of change streams. This is how microsoft recommends it:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/change-streams?tabs=csharp. Was not aware to not use the cosmos tag, will not do that now.

Comment: The output of change streams is a BsonDocument - the string you have put in your question is not a valid representation of a BsonDocument. So either you or some intermediate layer has changed it. If it was a valid BsonDocument you just insert it with a Mongo Client the same way as any other document